# About a proxy or connection manager for sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a WSO2 server that opens almost 700 simultaneous connections to the sql server for 10 minutes a day. This is a server that has a very high level of updates, you can't do a cache of any kind. This number of connections causes many deadlocks and makes the sql server very slow.

I have tried to limit the number of connections in the sql server, this causes an error in WSO2 and stops working, I have also tried to limit the number of connections in the WSO2 connection configuration with the same result.

I have seen that there are connection handlers for postgresql and mysql that queue requests but I haven't found one for sql server. Is there one?

Excuse my language, my native language is Spanish.

Comment: "*This number of connections causes many deadlocks and makes the sql server very slow.*" - This sounds like a query / index / process tuning issue, not a number of simultaneous connections issue. Deadlocks generally can be alleviated by making your queries run faster (which is a good idea to do in general). Additionally, looking into alternative isolation levels (such as RCSI) may be of benefit to you too.

Comment: "connection handlers [...] that queue requests" -- I don't believe such things exist, and even if they do, the effect would be the same as limiting the connection pool size, which you have already seen not working.

Comment: Not exactly, apart from WSO2 I have other connections and each connection does updates and inserts to 7 tables, the same tables and the same records. As the number of connections increases, the deadlock between them increases. I have no control over what the apps do so I can't fix the deaklock but I can decrease it. With the level of connections that I have, an update can take more than a minute.

Comment: Connection handlers (¿pools?) exist for mysql and postgres, I just haven't found one for sql server.

Comment: "*I can't fix the deaklock but I can decrease it*" - You'll probably find that decreasing the number of concurrent connections is going to have little affect on the deadlocks. SQL Server scans for deadlocks every 5 seconds, so even if your `UPDATE` queries runtimes cut in half, if they're still taking more than 5 seconds to run, and are part of the deadlock graph, then good chance you'll still get a good number of deadlocks. All the things my previous comment mentioned on how to improve deadlocks are outside of the app, and can be accomplished with no access to the app itself.

Comment: I don't think that using RCSI is the solution, the lifetime of a record is a few milliseconds and there is a complex logic to make decisions. The server handles money, there can be no errors. There is also the impact on memory, hard drives, tempdb, rollback transactions, etc.
With the number of connections I have, transactions easily exceed 30 seconds. If I manage to reduce the number of simultaneous connections to double or triple the number of server cores, I think it would improve a lot.

Comment: RCSI doesn't allow any more data errors than the default isolation level. In fact, it basically version controls the state of the data so that reads can occur on a version of the data at the point in time the read occurs, despite any concurrent writes occurring, and visa versa, to allow reads and writes to not block each other (very simply speaking). Unsure if you were stating you're worried about the impact on your hardware with RCSI, but there's generally no additional impact to be concerned about. Sure increasing hardware can help, but is expensive compared to just tuning the database side.

Comment: You also won't typically see the same magnitude of results by adding more hardware as you would with proper tuning. Also, if you're able to reduce the allowed connections, that means the end users are going to be waiting just as much for their queries to run, just the same (roughly) as by allowing more connections and the server resources being exhausted and / or more blocking is occuring. So from the high level perspective of the process, it doesn't get any faster on the whole, you're just shifting where the bottleneck is.

Comment: The problem with RCSI is precisely that it reads the data at a point in time, when the applications make their decision and are going to execute their action, since the data is old and invalid, they have to implement measures for this possibility and I don't have control over applications.
On youtube there is a video from the oracle development group that shows how reducing the number of concurrent connections increases the number of requests that the server can handle.

Comment: 'REUP_OLTP_Performance_-_Concurrent_Mid-Tier_Connections'.
It is also mentioned by HikariCP, https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/About-Pool-Sizing and by CockroachDB.
This is the formula provided by PostgreSQL, connections = ((core_count * 2) + effective_spindle_count).

Comment: "*it reads the data at a point in time, when the applications make their decision and are going to execute their action, since the data is old and invalid*" - This is a common misconception people make when trying to utilize *real-time data*. The data point isn't old, that's the valid state of the data at that point in time as the write transaction hasn't finished occurring yet. The state of the data as the result of the write transaction is a future state that will be the present state when the write transaction finishes. With the default isolation level, the app isn't getting the state of...

Comment: ...the data at that point in time (real-time) because it's locked waiting for the write transaction to finish. In my opinion that's actually the incorrect data point with *real-time data* because the app requested the state of the data at a different time from when it's actually receiving that data - but that would depend on the goal of the system I suppose.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137999/discussion-between-j-d-and-felix).